# Internet Explorer 9 takes a long time to load websites

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

IE9 on Windows 7 would load Google okay, and we could search on Google okay, but almost any other website would take an inordinate amount of time to load.  The loading sprite would sit there indefinitely.

I uninstalled IE9 to roll back to IE8, and the same issue occurs.

We've reset IE settings back to defaults, and there are no add-ons causing this.

Firefox loads websites fine on this computer.

Could it be an IE-specific virus/trojan?  IE was displaying an incorrect/hijacked home page.

**Update:** we found a trojan in the Dropbox cache folder, and deleted it, but the symptoms (and damage) remains.

We also tried registering some DLLS, but receive the following errors:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You try opening a command prompt, and running "sfc /scannow" without the quotes which checks all the Windows System files and attempts to repair them?

Answer (score 2):

Using IE9, I get exactly the same errors as you. The only dll which can be re-registered is jscript.dll, as well as jscript9.dll.

If your computer was infected, the best advice is always to reformat the hard disk and reinstall
Windows and all products from scratch. This is because the damage caused by a virus cannot
always be totally repaired, even if the virus was eradicated or disabled.

If you wish to try and repair Windows, start by doing [sfc /scannow](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html),
then follow with scans by several well-known anti-viruses.
Most anti-viruses offer online scans from the browser, each scan taking some
hours to complete.

If this is not enough, see also [How to Do a Repair Install to Fix Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).

Comment: Also consider a bootable virus scanner.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed the leftovers of some virus activity. The utility that I have had the most success with as far as fixing this problem is [malwarebytes](http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html?part=dl-10804572&subj=dl&tag=button). 9 times out of 10 malwarebytes will fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have had fantastic luck using [ComboFix](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/dl/12/) to not only remove malicious software, but to repair damage left over when other software removes a hostile piece of software.

This is a lightweight executable, and just runs from your C Drive.  I find that some malicious software actually blocks the execution of this app, so you can merely rename it from combofix.exe to ifix.exe or anything else you choose.

I have fixed similar behavior with combofix.